# VOLUME_SETTINGS deprecated on API 23 and now app is with errors

Tags: android, eclipse, android-6.0-marshmallow, deprecated

I updated an app to API 23. (min sdk 14 target sdk 23) Ok. The app was working fine up to API 21 but reading info at sites and forums I noticed that Android deprecated the VOLUME_SETTINGS function on Android M so this function appears as error in Eclipse.

What should I use instead of VOLUME_SETTINGS now? I didnt find any clue about this.

Here is the part that shows me the error:

```
        this.getContentResolver()
        .registerContentObserver(
                System.getUriFor(System.VOLUME_SETTINGS[AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC]),
            false, mVolumeObserver);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could just use something like this:

```
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, mVolumeObserver);
```

Hope this will help someone!